# Visual Studio 2010 crash with ObjectDisposedException

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010

Strange exception happens when I work in VS 2010. I'm creating web project and insert button. When I double click on the button to create onClick event, I get a message box from Visual Studio which says: "visual studio has encountered an exception. this may be caused by an extension. You can get more information by running the application together with the /log parameter on the command line, and then examining the file"

When I do that in cmd, it creates an ActivityLog file which has a few tags like this one:

```
<description>
    System.ObjectDisposedException: Cannot access a disposed object.&#x000D;&#x000A;Object name: &apos;TagAggregator&apos;.&#x000D;&#x000A;
        at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Text.Tagging.Implementation.TagAggregator`1.&lt;GetTags&gt;d__e.MoveNext()&#x000D;&#x000A;   
        at RemObjects.Oxygene.VisualStudio.Editor.MessageHighlightAdornmentManager.TextBuffer_Changed(Object sender, TextContentChangedEventArgs e)&#x000D;&#x000A;
        at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Text.Utilities.GuardedOperations.RaiseEvent[TArgs](Object sender, EventHandler`1 eventHandlers, TArgs args)
</description>
```

What does that mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That means that an extension that uses RemObjects.Oxygene has a bug.

Comment: But my extension doesn't use RemObjects.Oxygene.

Comment: Beg your pardon, but I don't know what software is installed on your computer. And I guess that http://www.remobjects.com/oxygene/ is installed.

Comment: But the extension which is the reason for the above mentioned exception doesn't use RemObjects.Oxygene.
And yes, Oxygene is installed.

Comment: What makes you believe that you know which extension is the source of the exception?

Comment: Because when I deactivate it, the exception isn't shown, and when I reactivate it, it is shown. And I know that it doesn't use RemObjects.Oxygene because I wrote the code for the extension.

Comment: Yes, but what? The exception says "Cannot access a disposed object". Which object is it?

Comment: I'm feeling fooled a little bit. The exception also says: Object name: 'TagAggregator'. And I strongly believe that your IDe has a debugger.

Comment: I'm NEVER using TagAggregator. The exception message doesn't help me at all. What does "at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Text.Tagging.Implementation.TagAggregator`1.&lt;GetTags&gt;d__e.MoveNext()&#x000D;&#x000A;   " mean?